# How to add application unit-tests in zephyr-rtos project

Tags: zephyr-rtos

How would like to start a new application using Zephyr RTOS, including unit-tests for the application sources. I have seen that Zephyr provides a test-framework z-test and a test runner sanitycheck.

My goal is to separate production code from the testing code using the following directory structure:

```
PROJECT_ROOT
|-src
|-test
```

The `src` folder shall contain the application sources. The `test` folder shall contain the unit tests for the application sources, potentially with multiple separate binaries.

How can I achieve this with the framework (west, sanitycheck) provided by Zephyr? How does the test application know where to look for the application sources?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not the correct way to do it, but I solved it as follows:

1. Create a directory structure as you did:

```
PROJECT_ROOT
|-src
|-test
```

2. Add a source file with the test code to test/ directory.

main.cpp:

```
#include <ztest.h>

/* Make private functions public for access. 
I think this is not a clean way to do it, but for my purposes it was just fine. */ 
#define private public

#include "../src/Classyouwanttest.h"

void test_function(void)
{
    Classyouwanttest classyouwanttest;

    /* your zassert instructions here: */
    zassert_equal(classyouwanttest.funcXY(...) , ..., ...);
}

void test_main(void)
{
    ztest_test_suite(common,
        ztest_unit_test(test_function)
    );
    ztest_run_test_suite(common);
}
```

3. When testing, add following line to prj.conf:

```
CONFIG_ZTEST=y
```

4. Make your CMakeLists.txt switchable between production and testing code:

```
...

option(TESTS "Run tests in test/" ON)
# option(TESTS "Run tests in test/" OFF)

if(TESTS)
    target_sources(app PRIVATE test/main.cpp)

    # add here all class files for productive code
    target_sources(app PRIVATE ...

else()
    target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.cpp)

    # add here all class files for productive code
    target_sources(app PRIVATE ...
endif()
unset(TESTS CACHE)

...
```

5. Build your code.
6. Connect your device and see the test result in a terminal. E.g. with minicom:

```
$ minicom -b 115200 -D /dev/ttyACM0
```

Documentation about Zephyr Testing you find here:
https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/test/index.html?highlight=test

Besides. If you want to use the test runner. They changed the name from  "sanitycheck" to "twister" (Zephyr version 2.5). You find it in the same scripts folder.